# Break a text file after every 15 minutes time interval based on time values and count average numeric value for "File Count" in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, text

I have a text file with around 2000 lines of data which reflect a 24 hour time period, and number of files opened at different times. I need to break a file at every 15 minutes interval and need to count and print average number of files opened at every  15 minute interval?

The file format looks like this :

```js
[
 |Time: 01:22:52.106 |File Count: 40
|Time: 01:22:52.402 |File Count: 45
|Time: 01:23:45.960 |File Count: 30
|Time: 01:23:46.231 |File Count: 30
|Time: 01:27:03.289 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:27:03.706 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 01:27:04.215 |File Count: 33 
|Time: 01:27:04.830 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:27:05.514 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:27:05.912 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 01:27:06.216 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 01:27:06.216 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:27:06.471 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:27:06.472 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:27:06.834 |File Count: 33
|Time: 01:33:58.900 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:33:59.357 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 01:35:41.991 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:35:42.635 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 01:35:43.276 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 01:43:04.393 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:43:04.669 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:48:53.450 |File Count: 30
|Time: 01:48:53.716 |File Count: 30
|Time: 01:48:54.129 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:48:54.316 |File Count: 30 
|Time: 01:53:52.937 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:53:53.212 |File Count: 30
|Time: 01:53:53.531 |File Count: 30 
|Time: 01:54:12.570 |File Count: 32
|Time: 01:54:12.834 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 01:58:10.622 |File Count: 29 
|Time: 01:58:52.862 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 01:58:53.133 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:58:53.432 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:59:44.771 |File Count: 31
|Time: 01:59:45.102 |File Count: 30 
|Time: 02:01:40.451 |File Count: 30
|Time: 02:04:18.265 |File Count: 32
|Time: 02:04:18.558 |File Count: 33
|Time: 02:04:18.919 |File Count: 32
|Time: 02:05:09.987 |File Count: 31
|Time: 02:05:10.725 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:05:10.942 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:05:11.572 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:09:09.052 |File Count: 32
|Time: 02:09:09.370 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:09:09.714 |File Count: 31
|Time: 02:10:42.097 |File Count: 32 
|Time: 02:10:42.312 |File Count: 33
|Time: 02:15:28.439 |File Count: 33 
|Time: 02:16:56.419 |File Count: 30
|Time: 02:16:56.764 |File Count: 29 
|Time: 02:16:57.105 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:16:57.403 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:19:44.922 |File Count: 0  
|Time: 02:19:45.200 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:20:00.930 |File Count: 31 
|Time: 02:20:01.281 |File Count: 30
|Time: 02:20:01.542 |File Count: 30
|Time: 02:20:34.771 |File Count: 31
|Time: 02:20:35.040 |File Count: 31
```

1 hour data looks like this , any suggestion for solutions ?

Comment: Please provide more information. Like shortest reproducible code.

Comment: This is a saved text file with 24 hour data , which need to be read with respect to time and divide at every 15 minute loops, and find average number of file counts at every 15 minute time loop. Unfortunately , i could not put a good  solution together yet , so asking for help.

Comment: is the text a string?

Comment: No its not a string , its an output which i saved as a text file from another logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution.
I guess you will need adjustments for the complete file.

```
const fs = require('fs'); 

// import text file
let text = fs.readFileSync('./files.txt', 'utf-8'); 

//split text file to array and remove all Unnecessary characters
let arr = text.split(/\[|\]|,|: |\|Time|\|File Count|\r?\n|\r/g);

// remove empty elements
let filterdArr = arr.filter((el) => {
  return el != "" && el !== " ";
})

//decler array for file data objects
let fileDataArr = [];

//populate file data array with objects in this form:
// { time: <miliseconds>, fileCount: <number> }
filterdArr.forEach((el, i) => {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    fileDataArr.push({
      time: getMiliseconds(el),
      fileCount: +filterdArr[i + 1],
    })
  }
});

// declere array for time periods
let timePeriodsArr = [];

// populate time eriods array with objects for each time period
for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  let hours = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
  for (let x = 0; x < 60; x += 15) {
    let mins = x === 0 ? '00' : x;
    timePeriodsArr.push({
      timePeriod: `${hours}:${mins}`,
      fileCountAvg: 0,
    })
  }
}

// get array length
let arrLng = timePeriodsArr.length - 1;

// for each time period get start and end time in miliseconds
timePeriodsArr.forEach((timeObj, i) => {
  let startMs = getMiliseconds(timeObj.timePeriod)
  let endMs = i + 1 < arrLng ? getMiliseconds(timePeriodsArr[i + 1].timePeriod) : 86400000;
  let counter = 0;

  // check for each file data object if fits the current time period and calculate the average
  fileDataArr.forEach((fileObj, x) => {
    if (fileObj.time >= startMs && fileObj.time < endMs) {
      timeObj.fileCountAvg += fileObj.fileCount;
      counter++;
    }
  })
  timeObj.fileCountAvg = Math.round(timeObj.fileCountAvg / counter);
});

// time to miliseconds function
function getMiliseconds(el) {
  el = el.split(/:|\./g);
  if (el.length === 4) {
    return (+el[0] * 60 * 60 + +el[1] * 60 + +el[2]) * 1000 + +el[3];
  } else {
    return (el[0] * 60 * 60 + el[1] * 60) * 1000;
  }
}

console.log(timePeriodsArr);
```

You can download the the working solution here: https://github.com/yochanan-sheinberger/break-text-file.git

Comment: I have another file for which I need to find average of decimal values , the rest logic is same as above , I think I am not getting right average value for that , do you have any suggestions Yochanan.

Comment: This file is same as the file i shared above , i need to put the same logic for "value" to find average , as it is in decimal ,  will  it require any changes to your code @yochanan sheinberger.

Comment: Here it is : ```javascript [ Time: 02:04:18.265 | Value : 52.337254, |Time: 02:04:18.558 | Value: 43.105881, |Time: 02:04:18.919 |Value: 62.392159, |Time: 02:05:09.987 | Value:  83.654743]  ``` and so on ....

Comment: It's basically the same logic. Just replace "File Count" with "Value" in line 7. And replace all appearances of "fileCountAvg" with "valueAvg" and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes , tried that , but it seems its not generating average decimal value in the output. It shows only average integer value.

Comment: refactor line 59 to this: `timeObj.fileCountAvg = timeObj.fileCountAvg / counter; `

Comment: Tried that too , unfortunately it shows " NaN" for all average values.

Comment: If you can upload the file somehow it will be the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224122/discussion-between-dev-tester-and-yochanan-sheinberger).